# AllJoyn: error in application closing

Tags: java, alljoyn

When I close my AllJoyn client application in java I obtain the following errors:

```
88.987 ****** ERROR LOCAL_TRANSPORT sessionless_0 .../LocalTransport.cc:931 | Local transport not running: ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.987 ****** ERROR SESSIONLESS sessionless_0 ...ter/SessionlessObj.cc:1742 | org.alljoyn.Bus.CancelFindAdvertisement returned ERROR_MESSAGE (error=org.alljoyn.Bus.ErStatus): ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.988 ****** ERROR SESSIONLESS sessionless_0 ...ter/SessionlessObj.cc:1400 | CancelFindAdvertisementByTransport failed for name implements='com.coap.rest' :: ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.988 ****** ERROR LOCAL_TRANSPORT sessionless_0 .../LocalTransport.cc:931 | Local transport not running: ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.988 ****** ERROR SESSIONLESS sessionless_0 ...ter/SessionlessObj.cc:1742 | org.alljoyn.Bus.CancelFindAdvertisement returned ERROR_MESSAGE (error=org.alljoyn.Bus.ErStatus): ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.988 ****** ERROR SESSIONLESS sessionless_0 ...ter/SessionlessObj.cc:1400 | CancelFindAdvertisementByTransport failed for name name='com.coap.rest.sl.*' :: ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.988 ****** ERROR LOCAL_TRANSPORT sessionless_0 .../LocalTransport.cc:931 | Local transport not running: ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.988 ****** ERROR SESSIONLESS sessionless_0 ...ter/SessionlessObj.cc:1742 | org.alljoyn.Bus.CancelFindAdvertisement returned ERROR_MESSAGE (error=org.alljoyn.Bus.ErStatus): ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.988 ****** ERROR SESSIONLESS sessionless_0 ...ter/SessionlessObj.cc:1400 | CancelFindAdvertisementByTransport failed for name name='org.alljoyn.sl.*' :: ER_BUS_STOPPING
88.989 ****** ERROR TCP     external          ...outer/TCPTransport.cc:3882 | TCPTransport::DisbleDiscovery(): Not running or stopping; exiting: ER_BUS_TRANSPORT_NOT_STARTED
88.989 ****** ERROR UDP     external          ...uter/UDPTransport.cc:10918 | UDPTransport::DisbleDiscovery(): Not running or stopping; exiting: ER_BUS_TRANSPORT_NOT_STARTED
88.989 ****** ERROR TCP     external          ...outer/TCPTransport.cc:3882 | TCPTransport::DisbleDiscovery(): Not running or stopping; exiting: ER_BUS_TRANSPORT_NOT_STARTED
88.989 ****** ERROR UDP     external          ...uter/UDPTransport.cc:10918 | UDPTransport::DisbleDiscovery(): Not running or stopping; exiting: ER_BUS_TRANSPORT_NOT_STARTED
88.989 ****** ERROR TCP     external          ...outer/TCPTransport.cc:3882 | TCPTransport::DisbleDiscovery(): Not running or stopping; exiting: ER_BUS_TRANSPORT_NOT_STARTED
88.989 ****** ERROR UDP     external          ...uter/UDPTransport.cc:10918 | UDPTransport::DisbleDiscovery(): Not running or stopping; exiting: ER_BUS_TRANSPORT_NOT_STARTED
```

The only thing I do when the application stops is to call the *leaveSession(sessionId.value)* function. Are there other things to do in order to fix my errors?

Some similar errors happen on closing the *JavaSDKDocAboutClient* sample application.

Comment: which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using AllJoyn v15.09a. Since the mine is a Java desktop application, I'm not using the Android SDK. I built the jar from source.

Comment: I tried with AllJoyn v15.09 but errors persist

Comment: since these happen on the samples I think they are spurious errors. The bug here, I think, is that these should be INFO or DEBUG.